# Please suggest a workflow for svn with local machine edits

Tags: svn, version-control, workflow

I'm working with some developers who have a habit of:

1. perform edits on their local machine (due to IDEs they like to use)
2. commit
3. update on the development "server"
4. test
5. repeat

This works, but for the normal development cycle it results in tons of tiny tiny commits. The problem is that due to the environment the code cannot be tested on the local machine. Therefore it has to be "sent" to the remote machine.

Of course, we could just edit on the remote server, but I'm looking for a way to use an IDE on a local machine.

I've tried using IDEs that support SCP or even sshfs, but it's all clunky. Especially when the code has to be saved as a different user on the remote machine.

I was hoping someone else had run into this and had a better way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `rsync` with ssh or [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) with the `/MIR` flag (if on Windows). This could work as long as each developer has a unique area on the server:

1. perform edit locally
2. run rsync/robocopy to server
3. commit when happy with the changes

If everyone is working on a common area on the server then this won't work as each person's sync will overwrite the other, so YMMV.